# Splunk Kafka Add-on doesn't read chef managed configuration files

Tags: apache-kafka, chef-infra, add-on, splunk

We are using Chef to manage our infrastructure, and I'm running into an issue where the Splunk TA (Add-on for Kafka) simply refuses to acknowledge I've dropped `kafka_credential.conf` file in the `local` directory of the plugin. If I use the "Web UI", it generates an entry properly and it shows up in the add-on configuration.

```
[root@ip-10-14-1-42 local]# ls
app.conf  inputs.conf  kafka.conf  kafka_credentials.conf
[root@ip-10-14-1-42 local]# grep -nr "" *.conf
app.conf:1:# MANAGED BY CHEF. PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY!
app.conf:2:[install]
app.conf:3:is_configured = 1
inputs.conf:1:# MANAGED BY CHEF. PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY!
inputs.conf:2:[kafka_mod]
inputs.conf:3:interval = 60
inputs.conf:4:start_by_shell = false
inputs.conf:5:
inputs.conf:6:[kafka_mod://my_app]
inputs.conf:7:kafka_cluster = default
inputs.conf:8:kafka_topic = log-my_app
inputs.conf:9:kafka_topic_group = my_app
inputs.conf:10:kafka_partition_offset = earliest
inputs.conf:11:index = main
kafka.conf:1:# MANAGED BY CHEF. PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY!
kafka.conf:2:[global_settings]
kafka.conf:3:log_level = INFO
kafka.conf:4:index = main
kafka.conf:5:use_kv_store = 0
kafka.conf:6:use_multiprocess_consumer = 1
kafka.conf:7:fetch_message_max_bytes = 1048576
kafka_credentials.conf:1:# MANAGED BY CHEF. PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY!
kafka_credentials.conf:2:[default]
kafka_credentials.conf:3:kafka_brokers = 10.14.2.164:9092,10.14.2.194:9092
kafka_credentials.conf:4:kafka_partition_offset = earliest
kafka_credentials.conf:5:index = main
```

Upon restarting splunk, the add-on is installed, and even the input is created under the Inputs section, but the cluster itself is "not available" and when examining the logs I see this:

```
2017-08-09 01:40:25,442 INFO pid=29212 tid=MainThread file=kafka_mod.py:main:168 | Start Kafka
2017-08-09 01:40:30,508 INFO pid=29212 tid=MainThread file=kafka_config.py:_get_kafka_clusters:228 | Clusters: {}
2017-08-09 01:40:30,509 INFO pid=29212 tid=MainThread file=kafka_config.py:__init__:188 | No Kafka cluster are configured
```

It seems like this plugin is only respecting clusters created through the WebUI. That is not going to work as we want to be able to fully configure this through Chef. Short of hacking the REST API, and fudging around with the .py files in the addon directory and forcing a dictionary in, what are my options?

Wondering if anyone has encountered this before.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess it is silently rejecting the files because `#` is not traditionally used for comments in INI files. Try a `;` instead.

Comment: Definitely not that as I've had the same result with and without the comments in them. :/ I'm doing some further digging through the python code and it looks like it hits up the built-in splunk configuration backend. So this actually seems like a splunk issue with splunk disregarding flat files on disk to get loaded into the Splunk REST Atom interface somehow..

Comment: Sounds believable.